# Check between MM-dd-yyyy and dd-MM-yyyy formats in Java

Tags: java

I have some data which contains date in different formats, eg: `yyyy-dd-MM`, `yyyy-MM-dd`, `EEE dd-MM-yy` etc.

I am trying to find a way to differentiate between `dd-MM-yyyy` and `MM-dd-yyyy`.
I understand that if dd is less than 12, there is no way I can be sure about format, However by identifying other cases when dd > 12, I can minimize the the wrong calculation.

**I tried this -**

```
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

try {
     Date date = originalFormat1.parse(s);    //I tried with s = "2013-25-8 20:10:00";

     cal.setTime(date);

     if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > 12)
                date = originalFormat2.parse(s);

     System.out.println(targetFormat.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
     System.out.println("Error");
```

**Output**

I was expecting : Sun, 2013-Aug-25 08:10:00 PM

But I got : Thu, 2015-Jan-08 08:10:00 PM

Comment: It's reading 25 as month, and automatically adding 2 year(= 24 month) in year and printing remaining 1 month as Jan. How can I correct it?

Comment: You really should rather fix your input. Guessing the format half the time doesn't seem like a good option.

Comment: You should first check why does your data sheet has dates in different formats. It is better to fix the root cause rather than fixing the symptoms.

Comment: You tried to parse the test date via `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` format. However, is 25 a valid month value? Remember that, in Java, months are 0-indexed, thus `Calendar.JANUARY` corresponds to value 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
originalFormat1.setLenient(false);
```

before you try to parse a string with it; that should make it throw a `ParseException` when the month number is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply format 1 and it interprets 25 as month then the date starts to become weird, that makes sense as month cannot be bigger than 12. Therefore, your if statement doesn't make sense. You have to check the format before applying the SimpleDateFormat (for instance with Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5,7) > 12).

Answer (score 0):

Hey actually it is taking 25 as month, So 12 + 12 + 1 means 2 years and one month i.e "January"
So, your date becomes :  "Thu Jan 08 20:10:00 GMT 2015" and again when you are changing it into "targetFormat" , this unusual result ensues...